# Problem with sort() and knit function in R

Tags: r, sorting, knitr

**Problem:**
I have an .Rmd file of an analysis that I'm trying to knit without success. I've created a toy example of the code that is causing the knit to fail. I am able to execute this example code chunk in R:

```
subject <- c('1', '3', '2')
run <- as.factor(c('run1', 'run2', 'run3'))
sample_df <- data.frame(subject, run)
sorted_df <- sample_df[ order(subject, run), ]
kable(sorted_df)
```

With the following output returned:

```
|   |subject |run  |
|:--|:-------|:----|
|1  |1       |run1 |
|3  |2       |run3 |
|2  |3       |run2 |
```

However, when I attempt to knit the document, the knit fails with the following error:

[image: error message]

The rest of the document does knit successfully with this code removed.

**Additional info:**

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.1                         
year           2018                        
month          07                          
day            02                          
svn rev        74947                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray
```

Comment: Fourth line doesn't work for me in R proper either. See if it works for you in a fresh R session.

Comment: Well, that's upsetting. Line 4 in fact no longer works me me either. I swear it had initially (though that was prior to updating R to the latest version) I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Alright, this works in place of line 4. Same error though. sorted_df <- sample_df[ order(subject, run), ]

Replaced it in the post.

Comment: Are you running exactly this? Or are `subject` and `run` only defined inside your data.frame in your real code? Maybe you need `sorted_df <- sample_df[ order(sample_df$subject, sample_df$run), ] ` (which is usually how that's done in base R). I can't reproduce the error with the code you provided,

Comment: Yes, thank you @MrFlick! I do have additional variables, but only want to retain subject and run. I ended up using something along the lines of : 
    sample_df <- sample_df[order(sample_df $subject, sample_df $run), c('subject' , 'run')]